# How to stuck an Area2D when it collide to Kinematic Body2D?

Tags: gdscript

I am Beginner. I am currently working a game of Bow and Arrow and I want to stuck the arrow in the Dart Board. When I shoot my player and arrow just stop when it collides but it didn't get move along to the position of Dart Board.
`func _on_Arrow_body_entered(body): if body.is_in_group("dart_board"): set_process(false)`
I want the if my Arrow(Area2D) enter body it will stop and stuck in the position of the DartBoard.

My Dart Board is moving using Path2D
I don't know how to get the position of the Dartboard and put it the position of the Arrow if it collides

Godot version I am using 3.5.1

I want to stuck the arrow while moving DartBoard

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to remove the dart from the scene tree and add it again in the same position... Well, not only position, also rotation, scale… The same transform.

First you are going to store the transform. You want the `global_transform` instead of the `transform` because the `transform` relative to the parent, and won't work.

So:

```
var tmp_transform := dart.global_transform
```

Then you remove the dart. Now, removing from the scene tree is not the same as deleting the node. So you are not going to `queue_free`, no, no, no. You are going to use `remove_child` (which is the opposite of `add_child`, makes sense?). Like this:

```
var tmp_transform := dart.global_transform
var dart_old_parent := dart.get_parent()
dart_old_parent.remove_child(dart)
```

And you will add the dart again, but as a child of the board…

But first, the board is the body you got. Except you get it as `Object`, you can cast it to `Node2D` (or to `PhysicsBody2D` to be as precise as you can be certain, or you can cast it to `Node` to be as flexible as you can, it makes little difference):

```
var board := body as PhysicsBody2D
```

*Or not cast it at all and rely on the fact types are optional in GDScript.*

Ok, now you will add the dart again, but as a child of the board. That way, when the board moves, the dart moves with it:

```
var tmp_transform := dart.global_transform
var dart_old_parent := dart.get_parent()
dart_old_parent.remove_child(dart)

var board := body as PhysicsBody2D
board.add_child(dart)
```

And make sure it has the same `global_transform`:

```
var tmp_transform := dart.global_transform
var dart_old_parent := dart.get_parent()
dart_old_parent.remove_child(dart)

var board := body as PhysicsBody2D
board.add_child(dart)
dart.global_transform = tmp_transform
```

That should do the trick. And yes, it could be shorter, for example:

```
var tmp_transform := dart.global_transform
dart.get_parent().remove_child(dart)

(body as PhysicsBody2D).add_child(dart)
dart.global_transform = tmp_transform
```